# Sending multiple UDP packets with CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, networking, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a lot of switches in my network which I try to check if they are online. I do this with a small UDP packet to which they respond with an UDP packet of their own to tell me that they are there. In fact it is only one switch simulating 200 hundred for testing but this is not important.

Since I do not like to work low level if I don't have to I use https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket for the UDP thing.

It works... almost. When I ping for example 10 switches repeatedly (I ping them at the same time and then wait for all the responses) it seems to work for the first cycles but then after a few it gets out of hand and almost all seem to not be responding. It is completely random which are and which not. It gets worse when I add more switches (meaning it does not work from the first cycle). With cycles I man: I send pings for all switches an then wait for all the answers (or timeouts) and then send the pings again.

When I check my network traffic with a packet sniffer I see that for the "wrong" switches (meaning they are shown as offline == timeout, but are actually online) there are three possible cases for each switch:

1. The packet from the iPhone is never send so no answer is received.
2. The iPhone send the packet but the switch did not respond.
3. The answer packet is received but the iPhone didn't read it.

It's completely random and they are mixed in one cycle.

When all the switches are actually online the problem is minimized (takes more cycles to appear) but still there .

Since the code is asynchronous there is a high potential for bugs and I think there must be some kind of race condition or something.

I will post my ping class here. It is not very complicated. I stared at this for hours but could not find a bug.

The usage is the following:
You create an instance with:

```
- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout delegate:(id<NMASwitchPingerDelegate>)delegate;
```

Than you just call the following method for every ipAddress you want to ping. The method returns immediately. This means the pings are processed concurrently:

```
- (void)sendPingToAddress:(NSString*)address;
```

I added it to a paste bin for your convenience: http://pastebin.com/0LuiXsXY

```
#import "NMASwitchPinger.h"

/**
 *  Private interface.
 */
@interface NMASwitchPinger () {
    /**
     *  The delegate of this class.
     */
    __weak id<NMASwitchPingerDelegate> delegate;
    /**
     *  The timeout after which the pinger stops waiting for a response.
     */
    NSTimeInterval timeout;
    /**
     *  The socket which is used to send the ping.
     */
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *socket;
    /**
     *  List of pings which are awaiting a response.
     */
    NSMutableDictionary *pendingPings;
    /**
     *  Dispatch queue which serializes access to the pendingPings dictionary.
     */
    dispatch_queue_t pendingPingsAccessQueue;
    /**
     *  The queue on which the delegate methods of the socket are executed.
     */
    dispatch_queue_t socketDelegateQueue;
    /**
     *  Is set to true when the SwitchPinger started receiving responses (after first send)
     */
    bool receiving;
}
@end


@implementation NMASwitchPinger

#pragma mark - Initialization

- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)newTimeout delegate:(id<NMASwitchPingerDelegate>)newDelegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // setting passed values
        timeout = newTimeout;
        delegate = newDelegate;

        // init data structures
        pendingPings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        pendingPingsAccessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("de.nexans-ans.pingerPendingAccess", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

        // create the socket for udp sending
        socketDelegateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("de.nexans-ans.pingerDelegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        socket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:socketDelegateQueue];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use the designated initializer");
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark - Sending a ping

- (void)sendPingToAddress:(NSString *)address {
    // we allow only one ping at a time to the same ip
    __block BOOL alreadyInList = NO;
    dispatch_sync(pendingPingsAccessQueue, ^{
        if (pendingPings[address]) {
            alreadyInList = YES;
        } else {
            pendingPings[address] = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        }
    });

    // don't send a second ping to the same address
    if (alreadyInList) {
        NSLog(@"SimplePinger: did not send ping because already a ping pending to this addres: %@", address);
        return;
    }

    // create a minimal packet (3 bytes)
    NSMutableData *packet = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    uint16_t vendor_value = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(266);
    uint8_t request_type = 1;
    [packet appendBytes:&vendor_value length:sizeof(vendor_value)];
    [packet appendBytes:&request_type length:sizeof(request_type)];

    // send over the wire
    [socket sendData:packet toHost:address port:50266 withTimeout:timeout tag:0];

    // schedule timeout handler
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, pendingPingsAccessQueue, ^(void){
        [self removeTimedOutPingWithAddress:address];
    });

    // start receiving when not already receiving
    if (!receiving) {
        bool recvGood = [socket beginReceiving:nil];
        NSAssert(recvGood, @"SimplePinger: could not start receiving");
        receiving = YES;
    }
}


#pragma mark - GCDAsyncSocket delegate

- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext {
    NSString *ipAddress = [GCDAsyncUdpSocket hostFromAddress:address];

    __block BOOL pingStillPending = NO;
    dispatch_sync(pendingPingsAccessQueue, ^{
        NSDate *sendDate = pendingPings[ipAddress];
        if (sendDate) {
            [pendingPings removeObjectForKey:ipAddress];
            pingStillPending = YES;
        }
    });

    if (pingStillPending) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [delegate switchPinger:self didReceiveResponse:data fromAddress:ipAddress];
        });
    }
}

- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didNotSendDataWithTag:(long)tag dueToError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didnt send data");
}

- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didSendDataWithTag:(long)tag {
    NSLog(@"did send");
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

/**
 *  Removes a timed out ping. A call of this function gets scheduled when a ping is send.
 *
 *  @param address The address of the ping which should be removed.
 */
- (void)removeTimedOutPingWithAddress:(NSString*)address {
    NSDate *sendDate = pendingPings[address];

    if (sendDate) {
        NSLog(@"timeout: %@", address);
        NSAssert(fabs([sendDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) >= timeout, @"SimplePing: removed ping before timout");
        [pendingPings removeObjectForKey:address];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [delegate switchPinger:self didReceiveTimeoutFromAddress:address];
        });
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: One thing that came to mind reading through your code is that you should probably start receiving *before* you send the packet to eliminate any chance that the response arrives between when you send and when you start receiving.

Comment: Valid point but CocoaAsyncSocket is fully buffered. Furthermore calling receive before you send something results in an error. I rewrote the code without CocoaAsyncSocket directly ontop bsd sockets and GCD. Now it works.